# Ionic : this.http.get(...).map is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs, ionic3

In my following extract of code of Ionic 3,
even after adding all the imports for rxjs operator of map, still the issue persists.

> TypeError: this.http.get(...).map is not a function

my imports already added and code are as follows:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/Rx";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HTTP } from "@ionic-native/http";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

public method(): Observable<any> {
return this.http
  .get(this.getMethodUrl)
  .map(this.extractResponse)
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

> RxJs version : 5.2.11
>
> Ionic:
>
> ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.0
>
> (C:\Users\Genesis-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
>
> IonicFramework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11
>
> Cordova:
>
> cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
>
> Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.1
>
> System:
>
> NodeJS : v8.11.4 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
>   npm    :6.4.0
>   OS     : Windows 10

Even if this issue has been discussed and resolved on StackOverflow previously, none of them is working for me.

Any help will be profoundly appreciated!

Comment: If you're using rxjs6 then `map` no longer exists as a function on the `Observable`, you must now use lettable operators with `pipe`

Comment: current version of Rxjs is 5.2.11. I tried using .pipe() also but then the error I received was **TypeError: this.http.get(...).pipe is not a function**

Answer (score 3):

According to the official Ionic documentation (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/), the return type of `HTTP.get` is `Promise<HTTPResponse>`, not Observable. Therefore, you can't use Observable operators on that type.

In order to create an Observable from a Promise (RxJS 5), simply use:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
let httpResult$ =  Observable.fromPromise(this.http.get(this.getMethodUrl));
```

Here is your code with the use of Observable:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/Rx";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HTTP } from "@ionic-native/http";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

public method(): Observable<any> {
return Observable.fromPromise(this.http
  .get(this.getMethodUrl))
  .map(this.extractResponse)
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

For RxJS 6+, use the new `from` operator:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
let httpResult$ =  from(this.http.get(this.getMethodUrl));
```

Note: You're IDE might not be configured correctly, this type error should appear immediately (marked red).

Comment: IDE error:   **../node_modules/rxjs/Rx has no exported member 'from'**

Comment: Sorry I'm just seeing you are operating on Rxjs 5.2. Try to use Rx.Observable.fromPromise() I'll edit the post

Comment: Runtime Error:  **TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined**

Comment: The code snippet is not a complete version of your code, I'll add the complete one in an edit ;-)

Comment: After implementing your snippet, I am getting blank Runtime Error

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry, I would need the complete code to figure it out. Anyhow, I think your question is answered with just the hint that you get a Promise, not an Observable. You'd need to figure the rest out by yourself ;-)

Answer (score 2):

if you are using RXJS 6 use `pipe`

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map,catchError } from "rxjs/operators";

public method(): Observable<any> {
return this.http
  .get(this.getMethodUrl)
  .pipe(
     map(this.extractResponse),
     catchError(this.handleError)
  )
}
```

Comment: I tried using .pipe() also but then the error I received was **TypeError: this.http.get(...).pipe is not a function**

Comment: Upgrade Rxjs version
npm install rxjs-compat

Answer (score 0):

Ionic `http.get` is returning promises. Unlike angular `httpClient.get` (return as observable), so you have 3 options to solve this.

1. Change your code to use promise

   `this.http
    .get(this.getMethodUrl)
    .then(this.extractResponse) // change to .then
    ...`
2. Replace your ionic http service to angular `httpClient.get`. Not sure why you are not using `httpClient.get` at the first place.
3. Convert the promise to observable by using `fromPromise` like @ggradnig mentioned. However, suggest you to go with option 2.

Comment: I tried option 2 but then in Ionic:   `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Http -> ConnectionBackend]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Http -> ConnectionBackend]: NullInjectorError: No provider for ConnectionBackend! Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Http -> ConnectionBackend]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Http -> ConnectionBackend]:`

Comment: because u need to import the httpClientModule into your ngmodule `app.module.ts`. You need to understand the basic of how Angular work. There's impossible to wrote down every steps for you to follow.